# Common practice in database design?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am currently developing a contact management database and I've encountered the following questions:

1. Let's say that one **person** can have one **email address** but multiple **tel-number**, (i.e. 1:1 relationship with **email** and 1:n relationship with **tel**). Should I include the **email** attribute in the **person** table and make one extra table for **tel**? Will the following schema be considered "unclean" since only the tel-nr are stored in a seperate table?

   ```
   ╔════════╗   ╔══════════╗  
   ║ person ║   ║ pers_tel ║
   ╠════════╣   ╠══════════╣
   ║ pid    ║   ║ pid      ║
   ║ ...    ║   ║ tel      ║ 
   ║ email  ║   ╚══════════╝ 
   ╚════════╝
   ```
2. If so, do I only need to declare `pid` in the `pers_tel` table (FK referencing `person.pid`) as PK or should `tel` be PK as well?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is better to store data in a separate table (in your case). That way you can manipulate the data easily.

Table: `person`
PK: `PID`

```
+-----+-----+------------------+
| PID | --- |      email       |
+-----+-----+------------------+
|  01 | --- | john@email.com   |
|  02 | --- | Bishoy@email.com |
|  03 | --- | Atul@email.com   |
+-----+-----+------------------+
```

Table: `pers_tel`
PK: `PID` and `Tel`

```
+-----+-----+
| PID | Tel |
+-----+-----+
|  01 | 123 |
|  01 | 426 |
|  01 | 752 |
|  02 | 456 |
|  03 | 789 |
+-----+-----+
```

[image: Database Relationship]

If a person can have multiple email addresses as well, then you can create a table for that too.

Before you create the table, please take a look at the database normalization. Especially 1st (1NF), 2nd (2NF) and 3rd (3NF) normalization forms.

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm
- https://www.lifewire.com/database-normalization-basics-1019735
- https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/
- https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php
- https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/database-normalization-part-7-ef7225150c7f

Answer (score 0):

Your design is "clean" - or more formally, denormalized. Singular attributes of an entity (like email address) are stored as columns; multiple attributes (like phone numbers) are stored in related tables using a one-to-many relationship. The identifier of that relationship is the primary key.

PID cannot be the primary key in the pers_tel table, as there may be multiple instances of the same value. Instead, you may decide not to declare a primary key at all for that table, or to create an artificial key.

If there is another discriminator (e.g. "phone type"), you might include that as part of the primary key with PID as long as the business domain says "a person may have multiple phones, and each phone has a unique type identifier (e.g. "home", "mobile" etc.).

Combining PID and TEL into a single primary key is not a common design solution - the value of the attribute of the "person" table is not suitable for a primary key.